# if statement with string and numerical fields

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

i have texblocks wn01, wn02, wn03 .... wn15. Every field has text="0"
If field wn01.text 0 or "" i want to enter value of przerzucanie.
If field wn01.text other value, than check next textblock.text
But if statement doesnt enter, 
i=1,s=01, string.operator==returned false.
i tried ("wn"+s).Text but is not recognized

```
private void przerzucanie_wyniku()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
    {
        string s = i.ToString("00");
        if ("wn"+s==null||"wn"+s=="0")
        {
            "wn"+s.Text = przerzucanie;

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use English names for method names, it will maybe give us a clue regarding what you are trying to achieve, something like FlipTheResult() ?

Comment: in another methods i created double a,b. dwade_w1=a*b, przerzucanie= Math.Round(dwade_w1, 4).ToString(); they i call przerzucanie_wyniku(); example przerzucanie=3.05, then i want put 3.05 in wn01 if it is empty or have 0. When <>0,empty i want to find next empty control textblock. wn01 ... wn15 i my historical list of przerzucanie values. I do not know how to write the code to program know "wn"+s is name of textblock

Comment: Are wn01, wn02 string variables? It looks to me like you need an array of string: string[] wn = new wn[16]; Then you can assign a value to: wn[i] = "przerzucanie" where i is the one from for loop

Comment: wn01, 02, 03, ... 15 are textblocks.  <TextBlock Name="wn03" 
                                Text="0"
                                FontSize="18"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                />

Answer (score 2):

`"wn"` + something else can't ever be `null` or not start with `wn`.

What you are doing I think is trying to find the textbox with a specific name instead of concatenating strings. If that is what you need, you have to walk the visual tree to find it. [Here an example how to do that in WPF.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759923/993547)

Comment: i have texblocks, they are historical memory of przerzucanie, wn01 has value of first counting, wn02 second value of przerzucanie, wn03 .... . If wn01 is <>0 or <>"" then check wn02, if wn02=0 then wn02=przerzucanie, if not 0 or empty the check wn03 and next, next

Answer (score 0):

This will never be true:

```
        if ("wn"+s==null||"wn"+s=="0")
```

This will always show "wn*".

Comment: i want (wn+s).text but i do not know how to write code. to get loop wn01.text, wn02.text

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
string w = "wn" + s;

if(w==null||w=="0"){}
```

Comment: string.operator == returned false bool

Comment: works: if (w == null || w == "0"||wn01.Text=="0"). But it works when i write wn01.Text. Your string w doesnt have after dot text option

Answer (score 0):

answear is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)s7.Children[i];
                if (tb.Text == "0")
                {
                    tb.Text = przerzucanie.ToString();
                    break;
                }
```